# Redirect to 'www' prefix domain using nginx

Tags: server, dns, nginx, ruby

I brought a domain in godady and I have Installed Passenger + Nginx on a Linux/Unix(Ubuntu) server and deployed a Ruby app. Now my domain looks something like  **http://example.com** when I try to request from a browser.
But I want my domain to default redirect to **www** every time it is requested from a browser(like **http://www.example.com.**).

example.conf

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    # return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
    # Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
    root /var/www/example/public;

    # Turn on Passenger
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_spawn_method direct;
    passenger_min_instances 1;
    #passenger_pool_idle_time 0;
    rails_env development;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/wrappers/ruby;
    passenger_sticky_sessions on;


}
```

uncommenting the line

> return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;

is throwing the error

```
www.example.com redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

I am forced to manually type **www.example.com** in the browser. Instead, how can I redirect to **www** by default?

Any Help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically need two `server` configuration chunks:

- One for `www`;  to be redirected to base domain only
- One for the base domain

Here is an example to get you started:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;

    location / {
        # Redirection happens here
        return 301 http://example.com$request_uri;
    }
}


server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name example.com;

    # Other conf directives go here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to make use of NGINX `if` statements. Simply put the following in your virtual host configuration:

```
if ($host = "example.com") {
    return 301 $scheme://www.$host$request_uri;
}
```

and be sure to replace "example.com" with your domain name.

**While this is the simplest way I've found, it's not the best.** The recommended route is to create a separate `server` block for non-www, and put the `return` statement there.

Comment: `if` does some nasty things, and this will actually break HTTPS configurations too as it'll end up in an infinite redirection loop even for HTTPS requests.  You should always use two individual server blocks; one for non-SSL and one for SSL.  Or, one server block for one set of server names, and then test the scheme, but if is still odd.

Comment: According to [If Is Evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/), `return` and `rewrite` can be safely used. I use this setup for a few of my sites, and it causes no errors and works as expected.